# Caching used to read data from xml file on first time WCF service request

Tags: xml, wcf, caching, service

I have a WCF Service as a host with basic http binding and allow one request at a time, as a singleton, I need to read some data from an XML file. Currently, we are getting the key value pair data from web configuration file. The first time we read the data, we want to keep it  in cache such that the application requests/get the data/value from existing cache. Based on search and from the available 4.0 options, it is advisable and easier to maintain values in web configuration. It looks like 4.0 introduced WCF cache that can be used, but, is it applicable in this scenario and will there be a performance concerns with regard to getting values/data from xml file rather than from web configuration. Please provide suggestions and inputs.

Comment: This WCF service accepts input values from client application and returm some error code and messages. I want to have a list of error code values in a sepearte file instead of storing in web config app settings.

Comment: It's not exactly a WCF cache..but, an in-process memory cache, which can be found in the System.Runtime.Caching.dll assembly.With this available,we don't need to rely on ASP.NET framework(system.web). Does anyone have a example of using an ObjectCache to cace values from name and value pair data from xml file,please pitch-in.Thanks. 

System.caching The 4.0 fremae